# how to passing multiple value from toast to multiple TextView?

Tags: java, android, textview, toast

I would like to know, how to pass multiple value from Toast to multiple TextView. I have two classes, MainActivity and LoginActivity. The Toast originally show in MainActivity class, but I would like to show the value from toast to the TextView in LoginActivity class.

here are the part of my code in MainActivity :

```
double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
  // show Toast
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Lokasi latitude: " + latitude + " Longitude : " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);
      startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Which one you want to pass..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your mainactivity class:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);
i.putExtra("val1",latitude);
i.putExtra("val2",longitude);
startActivity(i);
```

in your loginactivity class

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
int value1 = extras.getInt("val1");
int value2 = extras.getInt("val2");
```

then show this value in text view:

```
textview1.setText(String.valueOf(value1));
textview2.setText(String.valueOf(value2));
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on which activity comes up first , If the login is next after the main so you need to save the latitude and longitude some where as variable and then pass it as extras to the LoginActivity,

```
  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);
  i.putExtra("lat", latitude);
  i.putExtra("lng", longitude);
  startActivity(i);
```

and in the login activity read them in onCreate from the intent ...

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to look into the Bundle class. You can instantiate a Bundle and send over Strings, integers, etc.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Dashboard.getInstance(), Overview.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putLong("userId", u.getServerId());
intent.putExtras(bundle);
Dashboard.getInstance().startActivity(intent);
```

Is how I have done it in my application.

you can then access the data in the activity onCreate

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
userId = bundle.getLong("userId");
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all data(latitude, longitude) into intent extras, and then extract it inside the onCreate of LoginActivity and show the toast there...

Main activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);     
i.putExtra("lon", longitude);
i.putExtra("lat", latitude);
startActivity(i);
```

LoginActivity:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Lokasi latitude: " + getIntent().getExtras().getLong("lat")+ " Longitude : " + getIntent().getExtras().getLong("lon"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the value to the LoginActivity.class by passing value via Intent.
i.putExtras("fieldname","your value");

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple. Here is the sample code how to show value in textview.

```
Example 1 : (Two TextView)

TextView tv = (TextView)findViewbyId(R.id.your_element_id);
tv.setText("Lokasi latitude: " + latitude);

TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewbyId(R.id.your_element_id1);
tv.setText(" Longitude : " + longitude);

Example 2 : (One TextView)

TextView tv = (TextView) findViewbyId (R. id. your_element_id);
tv.setText("Lokasi latitude: " + latitude + "\n" +
            " Longitude : " + longitude);
```

you no need of two different textview for showing two different value. I dont know your requriment but still i am giving an option.

And one more thing, according to code the values are in double, Textview support only string value. So you have to convert double to string value, here is the example how to convert double to string

```
String value1 = String.valueof(latitude);
String value2 = String.valueof(longitude);
```

Now you can pass value to textview like this

```
tv.setText("Lokasi latitude: " + value1);
tv1.setText(" Longitude : " + value2);

(or)

tv.setText("Lokasi latitude: " + value1 + "\n" +
            " Longitude : " + value2);
```

I hope you got some thing :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass that value with **Intent** in **LoginActivity** which is in **latitude & longitude**.

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);
mIntent.putExtra("lat",latitude);
mIntent.putExtra("lon",longitude);
startActivity(mIntent);
```

And get the value of latitude & longitude in **LoginActivity** and set it in **TextView** using.

```
double latitude = getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("lat");
double longitude = getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("lon");

tv_lat.setText(String.valueOf(latitude));
tv_lon.setText(String.valueOf(longitude));
```

Its working for me perfect, I hope for you also. Try it.